# Make function execute after user hovers over link for 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yes, I know this question has been asked before, but I can't find an answer that works. This is an accepted answer from one of the other questions:

```
$('#element').hover(function()
{
    $(this).data('timeout', window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        alert('hovered for 2 seconds');
    }, 2000));
},
function()
{
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    alert('mouse left');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nCcxt/

As you see it doesn't do what it's supposed to.

What I need is simple in theory but I can't get it to work - when a user hovers over a link for 2 seconds, a function is called. If the user moves the mouse away before 2 seconds pass, nothing happens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code [works perfectly fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/nCcxt/1/). It only breaks due to the  `alert()` calls which causes the mouseout event to be triggered.

What do we learn from it? **Do not use `alert()` in combination with focus/hover/mousemove-related events.**

By the way, there are already jQuery plugins available for what you want to do: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html