# How to have a mouseover event fire only if the mouse is hovered over an element for sometime

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the background of a button when a user puts the mouse over the button for sometime. I would like to change the background only if the mouse is left over the image for one full second so as to mistakenly mouse crossing over the button.

I used the following code but unfortunately no result. Can you please identify where I made the mistake?

```
<html>
<script>
  var stillmouseover=0;

  function bcAnimation(y){  
    setTimeout(   function(){if (y.addEventListener('mouseover')) {stillmouseover = 1; } }, 2000);
    if (stillmouseover == 1) { y.style.backgroundColor = "Red";  }
  }
</script>

<body>
<button id='x' onmouseover="bcAnimation(this);" style="width:100;height:100;border:2;">i</button> <br> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best thing you can do is step through your code in a debugger. Not only will you figure out the problems with your code, you'll learn how to figure out future problems in your future code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am doing it for quite sometimes. But I think I have made some conceptual mistake. Because If I use any test alert within the if block, it is not coming up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make function execute after user hovers over link for 2 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063069/make-function-execute-after-user-hovers-over-link-for-2-seconds)

Comment: This question has no jQuery in it though, `onhover` doesn't exist in plain JS.

Comment: If the answer below was helpful, following up on it would be appreciated.